# Prevent padding of wrapped pseudo element with empty content

Tags: css, pseudo-element

When adding a background image in a standard block display `div` via pseudo classes like this:

```
.outer {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
.outer:before {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    content: " ";
}
```

the outer div ends up being padded by a few px at the bottom relative to the contained :before element. Is it possible to avoid this? The padding goes away if the `content` is replaced by non-empty text, but then I'd need a way of making the text invisible.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Ja5d/

Comment: Sounds like a whitespace issue. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 ways to get rid of that space. *(your generated box stand on baseline, like text. it leaves room for letters like : g,j,p,q,y)*.

1. set `vertical-align:top` or `bottom` to your inline-box
   http://jsfiddle.net/7Ja5d/2/
2. set your boxe as a `block` http://jsfiddle.net/7Ja5d/1/

Comment: Note: both of these will break when text is added to the outer div.

Comment: it already does on first place :) , question is about the gap under an inline-boxe i believe

Comment: +1 for the first solution, here is another solution http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/7Ja5d/7/ it's suitable if the heights of both child and parent should be always the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because your inner element is an inline-block it is observing the line height style, so just set:

```
.outer{ line-height: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Ja5d/5/

Hope that helps

Comment: We can also set `font-size:0;` instead. Looks like we have about 5 solutions at all (not including the very ugly hack by setting `color:transparent` when using a non-space character for `content`).

Answer (score 0):

Add height to .outer and set pesudo height to 100% http://jsfiddle.net/7Ja5d/8/

```
    .outer {
      background-color: red;
      text-align: center;
      height: 200px;
    }

    .outer:before {
      background-color: blue;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100%;
      content: " ";
    }
```

Also if you want to make text invisible just set "color: transparent;"